# terraform remote state cannot find attribute

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Experiencing issue that the data.terraform remote state cannot find the attribute, but it exists under outputs.

Data code:

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "network" {
  backend = "azurerm"

  config = {
    storage_account_name = ""
    container_name       = ""
    key                  = ""
    resource_group_name  = ""
    access_key           = ""
  }
}
```

Trying to get vnet, tried with .outputs.vnet also!

```
  vnet = "${data.terraform_remote_state.network.vnet}" // Also tested outputs.vnet and vnet_id, outputs.vnet_id
```

From my remote statefile:

```
"outputs": {
                "resource_group": {
                    "sensitive": false,
                    "type": "string",
                    "value": "xxx"
                },
                "vnet": {
                    "sensitive": false,
                    "type": "string",
                    "value": "xxx"
                },
                "vnet_id": {
                    "sensitive": false,
                    "type": "string",
                    "value": "xxx"
                }
            },
```

Error:

> - module.jenkins_service.var.vnet: Resource 'data.terraform_remote_state.network' does not have attribute 'vnet'
>     for variable 'data.terraform_remote_state.network.vnet'

Comment: Resolved.. The statefile did not have outputs as it was claimed.. This was corrected now.

Comment: You can post this an answer and mark it as accepted. That will help others find it faster.

Answer (score 0):

Earlier version of terraform azurerm you needed to rely on terraform_remote_state and generic outputs to pass data to downstream terraform runs.  The preferred method is to source data as a first class type. For example [azurerm_virtual_network](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/virtual_network.html) as [data sources](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/data-sources.html).